# Angular 7 Date Range Picker Issue

Tags: angular7, daterangepicker

I am using angular date range picker. I am able to use range selection successfully, however, while using presets like "Last 7 Days", "Last 14 months", etc, I get the following error causing the date range picker to break:

> ```
> Type Error: date.clone is not a function
> at MomentDateAdapter.clone (vendor.js:sourcemap:97931)
> ```

HTML code :

```html
<ngx-mat-drp (selectedDateRangeChanged)="updateRange($event)" [options]="options" #dateRangePicker>
</ngx-mat-drp>
```

what's wrong with this?